# Assigning role on registering a user in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm registering a user and assigning a  role(s) on sign up. I can't seem to figure out how to select a role an send it to the api.

The request

```
{
    "username": "Abdul",
    "fullname": "Gabriel Abdul ",
    "department": "IT Department",
    "email":"abdul@essex.com",
    "role":["admin"]
}
```

AuthService

```
 registerEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any>{
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
    const body=JSON.stringify(employee);
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'register-employee',body , {'headers':headers} )
  }
```

Employee Interface

```
export class Employee{
    username!: string;
    fullname!: string;
    department!: string;
    email!: string;
    role: string[];

}
```

RegisterEmployee.ts

```
......

employee: Employee = new Employee();
  errorMessage = "";
  isSuccessful= false;
  isRegistrationFailed= false;

  registerEmployee(){
    this.authService.registerEmployee(this.employee).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful= true;
  this.isRegistrationFailed= false;
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isRegistrationFailed = true;
      }
    )
  }
```

RegisterComponent.html

```
<form *ngIf="!isSuccessful">
               <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" 
              name="fullname" [(ngModel)]="employee.fullname"
              placeholder="Full Name"> </div>
                
              
             <div class="form-group">   
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" 
             name="username" [(ngModel)]="employee.username"
              placeholder="Username">
              </div>
                   
             <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="email" 
             name="email" [(ngModel)]="employee.email"
              placeholder="Email">
              </div>
                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <select class="form-control custom-select browser- 
              default" name="role" [(ngModel)]="employee.role" required
                            style="padding-top: 16px; font-size:19px">
                    <option value="receptionist">Role Receptionist</option> 
                      
                            <option value="doc">Role Doctor</option>
                            <option value="admin">Role Admin</option>
                            <option value="lab">Role Laboratory</option>
                            <option value="pharmacy">Role Pharmacy</option>
                            <option value="nurse">Role Pharmacy</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                
                    <select class="form-control custom-select browser- 
                default" name="department" [(ngModel)]="employee.department"
                            required style="padding-top: 16px; font-size:18px">
                     <option value="OPD Department">OPD Department</option>               
                     <option value="IPD Department">IPD Department</option> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                
                    <br>
                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                
                        <button type="submit" (click)="registerEmployee()" 
                        [disabled]="!employee.username"
                            class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

On postman everything works fine, on my ui the issue comes when assigning the role from the above `option` tag . The error i'm getting from the server side says `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('doc')` when i select a `role doctor` as an example.

Here is how roles are set on my api

```
Set<String> strRoles = registrationRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role receptionRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_RECEPTIONIST)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(receptionRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role admin is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);

                        break;


                    case "doc":
                        Role docRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_DOCTOR)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role doctor is not found."));
                        roles.add(docRole);

                        break;
                    case "lab":
                        Role labRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_LAB)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(labRole);

                        break;
                    case "pham":
                        Role phamRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_PHARMACY)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(phamRole);

                        break;
                    case "nurse":
                        Role nurseRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_NURSE)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(nurseRole);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Role receptionRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_RECEPTIONIST)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(receptionRole);
                }
            });
        }
        employee.setRoles(roles);
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the stringify, you are sending a json not a text

```
 registerEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any>{
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'register-employee', employee, {'headers':headers} )
  }
```

Comment: still it brings the same error